# Why is this field not being serialized?

Tags: java, rest, jax-ws, jax-rs

My `Issue` entity was created from a DB table that has several fields (id, etc...). Each issue has as a field a list of Articles, which are stored in a separate DB table. Articles have a `int issueID` field, which is used to map them to the appropriate Issue (there is no corresponding column in the `issues` table): Ultimately, when an Issue object is constructed, I'm going to have it pull all of the articles whose issueID matches its ID, so that I can return a single serialized object that contains the issue data as well as a JSONArray representing its list of articles.

At this point, though, I'm just doing some testing - creating a few dummy Article objects and adding them to the articles collection. The problem is that, when I test GET requests on the Issue object, the JSONObject returned includes only the fields stored in the database (id, etc...) - no sign of the Article collection. Why is that?

I'm equally interested to know what other code you would need to see to answer this question: I've just begun teaching myself how to write web services and am still in the phase of wrapping my head around the broad concepts, so figuring out which of the moving parts has affects which behaviors - and which annotations are needed where - is ultimately what I'm trying to do.

That being the case, broader-based advice is welcomed.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "issues")
@XmlRootElement
public class Issue implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    ....//other fields 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "issueID")
    private Collection<Articles> articlesCollection;

    public Issue() {
    articlesCollection = new ArrayList<Articles>();
    Articles a = new Articles();
    a.setHeadline("butt cheese");
    articlesCollection.add(a);
    Articles b = new Articles();        
    articlesCollection.add(b);
    Articles c = new Articles();        
    articlesCollection.add(c);
            }
```

Comment: Is class `Articles` serialized ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the relationship initialization is lazy so when the `Issue` object is loaded the `articlesCollection` is not fetched unless used.

In your case seems its the same situation.

Explore [OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.html) if you do not intend to explicitly load `articlesCollection`. When your object serializes the `articlesCollection` will be loaded if you have configured `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter`.

Comment: Hmm, but aren't I "using it" by instantiating it and adding articles to it? Or does "using it" have to be deserializing it from the DB? Also - how would I go about explicity loading the `articlesCollection` - by executing a query to deserialize it from the DB?

Comment: Not sure about that constructor but have you checked if its getting executed and the articlesCollection is loaded. Also what you do to the Issue object i.e. how its getting serialized?

Answer (score 0):

Does your Articles Class also has @XmlType or @XMLRootElement Tag?
Onany generic class like `List<T>` jaxb expects that `T` is annotated with `@XMLType` or `@XMLRootElelemt`